# How to set up map component with SXA search?

Tags: sxa

I am trying to integrate search result with out of box SXA map component.For that-- I have created "address" template inheriting from IPOI template. Then I have created few address items under site/data/address folder. In Page I have added search box ,search result and Map component. I can see search result on page (with latitude and longitude)  also search box is working properly. But in Map , no POI is getting rendered.Only blank map is shown.

I am using SXA 1.9 and referred following blog.

https://michaellwest.blogspot.com/2016/10/build-location-finder-search-using-sxa.html

Search result:

[image: Address Result with Map]

Address Template:

[image: Address Template]

Comment: How did you wire up your custom POI template with Rendering variants found under /sitecore/content/*tenant*/*site*/Presentation/Rendering Variants/POI?

Comment: Where have you specified your custom POIs and selected them for that Map?

Comment: I have not selected custom POIs for Map component, I am trying to use search result for that. During debugging I saw, search result data is picked up by component-map.js but as in search result there is no "Geospatial" property  (which has Latitude,longitude etc fields) ,it was not getting accepted  . Then I have tried with Location Finder SXA component ,whose result has Geospatial property from solr , and those result is getting rendered on Map with default icon and my custom POIs. My problem is how to use search box and search result component with map.